# What is happening when a backslash with an asterisk (\*) is read?

Tags: compiling

I'm writing tutorial of TeX and I accidently typed `\*` and realized the compiler does not read it as an error. I know that adding `*` triggers `\ifstar` condition, but I'm curious that how compiler treat `\*`.

On Overleaf, it will not produce any error nor warnings, but it also didn't do anything visible(even a tiny space). What will compiler do when realize the control sequence token is "`\*`" ?

Comment: `\*` is a normal macro (normally, commands consist only of letters, but there is an exception for one-character-non-letter names like `\$`, `\%`, `\@`, `\>` and `\*`). It does not trigger `\@ifstar`. The macro is a 'discretionary multiplication sign'. In LaTeX it is defined as `\DeclareRobustCommand\*{\discretionary{\thinspace\the\textfont2\char2}{}{}}`. You can see it in action in `\parbox{1.5cm}{$(x+y)\*(x-y)$}` Compare that to `\parbox{5cm}{$(x+y)\*(x-y)$}`. The idea is that `\*` normally has no output, but becomes a multiplication sign if it happens to come after a line break.

Comment: Oh, I keeping thinking that it is a starred-version empty macro until this. This makes more sense to me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By itself, `*` triggers nothing. Only some commands will accept `*` for a variant, but they are defined in a special way. For instance, in LaTeX we have

```
% latex.ltx, line 6002:
\DeclareRobustCommand\vspace{\@ifstar\@vspacer\@vspace}
```

so if `\vspace` is followed by `*`, LaTeX will do `\@vspacer` (and gobble the asterisk), otherwise it will do `\@vspace`.

In plain TeX there is no `*`-variant (unless one defines the infrastructure and does a specific definition).

According to the tokenization rules, `\*` is a *control symbol* and it is defined in plain TeX and LaTeX to produce a “discretionary multiplication symbol”: if it is used for hyphenation, it will produce a thin space followed by character 2 in `\textfont2`, usually ✕, at the end of the line. It's normally (but not frequently) used in math mode.

An example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\parbox{0pt}{$x\*y$}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `\parbox` with zero width will force the `\discretionary` to be used.