# IEEE trans: Cite subfigure reference

Tags: xetex, pdftex, ieeetran

I have a figure that contains four subfigures with captions and I want to cite the subfigure. I tried a lot but it didn't work out. Below is not working

```
\usepackage{subfigure}
Some text \subref{fig:multi-scale} Figure \ref{fig:overall_figure}
```

**COMPLETE LATEX CODE**

```
%%%% ijcai21.tex

\typeout{IJCAI--21 Instructions for Authors}

% These are the instructions for authors for IJCAI-21.

\documentclass{IEEEtran}


% Use the postscript times font!
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{url}
%\usepackage[hidelinks]
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[small]{caption}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\urlstyle{same}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}%

%\usepackage{subfigure}
%\usepackage{caption}
%\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}


%\usepackage{cleveref}

% You need a newsubfloat element to use subcaption




\definecolor{mygray}{gray}{.92}

% thickline==============================================================================
\makeatletter
\def\thickhline{%
  \noalign{\ifnum0=`}\fi\hrule \@height \thickarrayrulewidth \futurelet
   \reserved@a\@xthickhline}
\def\@xthickhline{\ifx\reserved@a\thickhline
               \vskip\doublerulesep
               \vskip-\thickarrayrulewidth
             \fi
      \ifnum0=`{\fi}}
\makeatother

\newlength{\thickarrayrulewidth}
\setlength{\thickarrayrulewidth}{2\arrayrulewidth}
%======================================================================================

\title{Deep Learning}




\author{
Anonymous Author
\thanks{A. A is with the Department
of Electrical and Computer Engineering, Georgia Institute of Technology, Atlanta,
GA, 30332}% <-this % stops a space
\thanks{Anonymous and Anonymous are with Anonymous University.}% <-this % stops a space
\thanks{Manuscript Submission April 19, 2022; revised August 00, 0000.}}


\begin{document}


\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
  xxx
\end{abstract}

%
\begin{figure}[!t]
    \subfloat[Deep Residual Auto-Encoder]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{cat.jpg}}
    \label{fig:deep_residual}
    \vspace{10pt}
    \subfloat[Multi-scale network]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{cat.jpg}}
    \label{fig:multi-scale}
    \caption{Oversimplified view of single iterative networks for image compression}
    \label{fig:overall_figure}
\end{figure}


Cross references: \subref{fig:deep_residual}
and \subref{fig:multi-scale} of \ref{fig:overall_figure}


\small
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{ijcai21}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please include a full [MWE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/611205/119); this should be something that is compilable, and includes everything from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`.

Comment: Try `\protect\cite{...}`.  Be advised that the subfigure package is obsolete.  I believe that subcaption is now IEEEtran compatible.

Comment: @WillieWong this is my full research paper and it is hard for me to include here

Comment: @JohnKormylo How I can use \cite to cite subfigure. I already tried it but it did not work for me

Comment: Use subcaption package. Reference figures and subfigures with \ref-family commands. \cite should be used for citations of your references.

Comment: @FHZ I cannot use subcaption with subfigure

Comment: @KhawarIslam, oh, sorry, my mistake. I forgot to mention to use only the subcaption package. Subcaption and subfigure are incompatible, check [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13625/140133).

Comment: @FHZ Still i cannot solve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package `subfigure` has been obsolete and deprecated for several years. Its author provided the successor package `subfig`.

There is also a superior package called `subcaption`, but it is ***not*** compatible with `IEEEtran`:

```
Package caption Warning: Unknown document class (or package),
(caption)                standard defaults will be used.
See the caption package documentation for explanation.
```

The warning you get upon loading `subcaption` in a `IEEEtran` document means that captions will be overridden and this won't please the copy editor to whom you submit your article.

Solution: use `subfig`.

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text

\begin{document}

Cross references: \subref{fig:gdn_network}
and \subref{fig:multi_layer} of \ref{fig:overall_figure}

\lipsum

\begin{figure}[!t]
\centering

\subfloat[%
  GDN Network \cite{balle2016end}\label{fig:gdn_network}%
]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}}

\subfloat[%
  Multi-layer GDN Network \cite{balle2017end}\label{fig:multi_layer}%
]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}}

\caption{Global caption in the style IEEEtran defines\label{fig:overall_figure}}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2-12]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is not working. Cross references: ?? and ?? o

Comment: To correct have your references, you need to compile more than once.

Comment: @KhawarIslam Your `\label` commands are in the wrong place. Look more closely to my code.

Comment: @egreg oh my god, thank you so much. I was not expecting that type of error. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `caption` and `subcaption` packages you can define `\label` inside them.

The MWE follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}
\captionsetup{justification=centering}
\captionsetup[figure]{position=below}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{position=below}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\ref{fig:many_figures}, \autoref{fig:many_figures}. \ref{fig:gdn_network}, \autoref{fig:gdn_network}. \ref{fig:multi_layer}, \autoref{fig:multi_layer}.

\begin{figure}[!ht]
  \centering
  \caption{Many figures}
  \label{fig:many_figures}
  \subcaption{GDN Network\cite{balle2016end}}{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image}}
  \vspace{10pt}
  \label{fig:gdn_network}
  \subcaption{Multi-layer GDN Network \cite{balle2017end}}{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
  \label{fig:multi_layer}
\end{figure}

\ref{fig:fig_name}, \autoref{fig:fig_name}. \ref{subfig:fig_name-a}, \autoref{subfig:fig_name-a}. \ref{subfig:fig_name-b}, \autoref{subfig:fig_name-b}.

\begin{figure}[!ht]
  \centering
  \captionbox{Legend figure\label{fig:fig_name}}[\linewidth]{
    \subcaptionbox{Legend a\label{subfig:fig_name-a}}{
      \includegraphics[width=.2\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    }\;
    \subcaptionbox{Legend b\label{subfig:fig_name-b}}{
      \includegraphics[width=.2\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    }
  }
\end{figure}


\begin{thebibliography}{1}
  \bibitem{balle2016end}
  Balle 2016 Reference text
  
  \bibitem{balle2017end}
  Balle 2017 Reference text
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `caption` is not compatible with `IEEEtran`.

Comment: It did not work, I have checked it

Comment: And that's why we always ask OPs for MWEs. IEEEtran is cited in the title but nowhere else in the text or provided code.

Comment: @FHZ now i realized that now i have added whole code and you can produce this error easily